Do you need to use the power invariant or magnitude invariant Clarke transform to compute both back EMF and torque?
I'm working on a motor simulator and FOC driver and after internalising the wiki pages for the Clarke and dq0 transform I'm stuck as to which variant of the transforms to use.
Assuming I'm given the \$K_v\$ (or \$K_e\$) constant of the motor I can compute the torque constant
$$
K_t =K_e = \frac{1}{K_v}.
$$
I also have current sensors to measure the \$I_a\$, \$I_b\$ (and \$I_c = -I_a - I_b\$) phase currents in the ABC reference frame. Also I measure the motor position and track rotation speed \$\omega\$.
I'd like to estimate the torque on the rotor, and at the same time get the back EMF values in the ABC frame that the motor would produce under no load.
My understanding so far is that I should use the power invariant version of the Clarke/Park transform to get \$I_q\$ and then obtain
$$
\text{torque} = I_q \cdot K_t.
$$ On the other hand I have the back emf voltage in the DQ0 frame $$
V_q = K_v \cdot \omega,
$$ and as I understand, I need to use the magnitude invariant inverse transforms to get the \$V_a\$, \$V_b\$ and \$V_c\$ voltages. However... the relationship
$$
K_t = \frac{1}{K_v}
$$ is based on a power argument starting from the relation
$$
\text{torque}\cdot \omega = V \cdot I,
$$ which indicates to me I have to use the same transform for both \$V\$ and \$I\$. Can someone clarify this or point me to some further reading (something that mentions both torque and EMF)?
